# How would I update node.js inside of Docker container on Windows

Tags: node.js, docker

I am running into a problem finding good documentation on how to update and check the version of Node that runs on my Docker container. This is just a regular container for .net 2 application. Thank you in advance.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

To answer your questions directly:

If you **don't** have the Image's `Dockerfile`:

1. You can probably (!) determine the version of NodeJS in your container by getting a shell into the container and then running `node --version` or perhaps `npm --version`. You could try `docker run .... --entrypoint=bash your-container node --version`
2. You can change a running Container and then use [`docker commit`](https://docs.docker.com/engine/reference/commandline/commit/) to create a new Container Image from the result.

If you do have the Image's `Dockerfile`:

1. You should be able to review it to determine which version of NodeJS it installs.
2. You can update the NodeJS version in the `Dockerfile` and rebuild the Image.

It's considered bad practice to update images and containers directly (i.e. not updating the `Dockerfile`).

Dockerfiles are used to create Images and Images are used to create containers. The preferred approach is to update the Dockerfile to update the Image and to use the updated Image to create update Containers.

The main reason is to ensure reproducibility and to provide some form of audit in being able to infer the change from the changed Dockerfile.

Comment: I am new to Docker. can you elaborate "The preferred approach is to update the Dockerfile to update the Image and to use the updated Image to create update Containers"? If it is too long, can you direct me to an article or something. Thanks

Comment: @phoebe `Dockerfile`'s define the content of a container image. Commonly, they include `FROM` statements that define a parent image to use (as a basis). For NodeJS this may be e.g. `FROM node:XX as something`. My suggestion is to check the value of `XX` and, if it is not the current|latest version of NodeJS, to update the file to reflect that value and then rebuild the image using it. The documentation is here [`docker build`](https://docs.docker.com/engine/reference/commandline/build/)

Answer (score 0):

In your Dockerfile

`FROM node:14-alpine as development`